# Multiple kernel SVM is equal to one ANN - Is Kernel SVM better that one ANN?

Tags: neural-network, svm, kernel, ann

I'm comparing multiple Kernel SVM with one neural network, e.g one `ANN` with one hidden layer.

I have succesfully trained a neural network by using multiple Kernel SVM and it works absolutely perfect. The SVM algorithm is using quadratic programming, in this case it's Hildreth's algorithm for the SVM. The training process is a feed forward process, not backpropagation.

The training time is about 15 seconds and I'm only using `yale` database of about 150 images. The multiple Kernel SVM gives me one large matrix `W` and one vector `b`.

$$y = \sigma(W*x + b)$$

Where $x$ is an image, constructed as one vector image.

**Question:**

I find multiple Kernel SVM very useful and I have trained a neural network before with the same amout of data. It gave less accuracy and took longer time to train.

Why is multiple Kernel SVM not so popular compared to regular neural networks?